# Access reading violation when pushing items to a vector in a constructor

Tags: c++

Although not new to programming, I'm relatively new to C++ and struggling to remember and understand it. I created a k-d-tree class which is already working, but I while writing it I struggled with the program crashing with an access reading violation 0x00000000 error.

Basically, the tree class has two property vectors to hold the items stored into the tree and to hold the children of the current branch respectively. As far as I've understood, you usually don't have to increase the size of vectors. However, here if I remove the line with `this->ownObjects.reserve(86);`, the program crashes when I'm trying to push items to the vector. Same happens with the children vector. Another weird thing is that the vectors have to be reserved for 86 items or more; otherwise the program crashes with the same message.

It's probably something very simple (or I'm doing something wrong), but I'm not used to C++ enough to get it. It's an ugly workaround that I would like to resolve, and I'm also interested in the reason behind that behavior. And being a k-d tree class, it's very expensive and unacceptable for memory usage.

I tried to keep the code as short as possible, but there shouldn't be anything relevant missing. What I've been speculating is that it might be a problem with a vector of objects and memory allocation, or a feature related to C++ constructors that I don't know of. Is it something with C++ that I don't understand, or something else?

header file

```
[...]

class KDTree {
private:
    Vector3 maxBounds;
    Vector3 minBounds;
    std::vector<Triangle> ownObjects;
    std::vector<KDTree> children;

public:
    KDTree();
    KDTree(const Vector3 &maxBounds, const Vector3 &minBounds, AlignedArray<Triangle> &objects);
};
```

.cpp file

```
[...]

KDTree::KDTree() { }

KDTree::KDTree(const Vector3 &min, const Vector3 &max, AlignedArray<Triangle> &objects) :
    maxBounds(max),
    minBounds(min),
    ownObjects(),
    children()
{
    this->children.reserve(128);
    this->ownObjects.reserve(85); // No errors if these values are changed to 86 or more.

    for (size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) 
        this->ownObjects.push_back(objects[i]); //The program crashes here.

    [...] 

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        // Another crash here if the this->children.reserve(128); earlier is not called. The groups[i] is a filtered vector of items from the objects array.
        children.push_back(KDTree([.. tested valid parameters ..]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `AlignedArray`?

Comment: How mant itesm does objects contain? around 40 ?

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, sorry, forgot that. For this code its functionality is exactly same as for a vector. The error also occurs when I'm pushing KDTree objects to the children vector, so I'm quite sure the AlignedArray class is not relevant here.

Comment: Please show the code where you call the constructor. It seems like objects is NULL.

Comment: @MoustafaS Any amount up to hundreds of thousands.

Comment: Another possibility is that Triangle is a value type and has a faulty copy constructor / operator

Comment: @NineBerry The program works as intended if reserve is called on the vectors for 86 or more items like in the example; the contents of objects don't change. Additionally, the objects[i] can be used before the push_back call without errors.

Comment: Also use ASAN and Valgrind to see if there are memory errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Spike just because a program is working does not mean that it is bug free. Also are you sure that i = 0; i < 8; will never index into garbage?

Comment: Add the code for the the `Triangle` class, you say the error manifests when the `this->ownObjects.reserve(85);` line is removed but we can't see what's happening when in this class

Comment: @josefx I tested the children.push_back line without using the index at all (using the empty constructor with no parameters) and the code still crashed on the same line. 
So the only line inside the for loop:
children.push_back(KDTree());

Comment: @Tony I'm afraid I cannot show the Triangle code, but I proceeded to test the code with removing all the references to the Triangle class. The error with ownObjects vector vanished, but the code still crashes on the children.push_back(KDTree()); line.

The changes I made to test the impact of the Triangle class: objects is an empty AlignedArray<int>, and ownObjects is vector<int> type.

Comment: @Spike -- *I'm afraid I cannot show the Triangle code* -- Well all rests on whether `Triangle` and `KDTree` are safely copyable since you insist using those two types used in `std::vector`.  Since you don't want to show these classes, then you're going to have to determine this.  No one can determine whether these classes are ok to be used in vector unless they see the code for themselves.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, I did provide the code for the KDTree class, and the crash still occurs even if I remove all references to the Triangle class from the code.